# Unable to Load Database project in VS2008

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-2008-express, database-project

I have Database project which I'm unable to load in VS2008 and I have SQL Server 2008 Express edition installed on my machine..

I get following error message, when I try to load

> Database projects require a connection
>   to a local instance of Microsoft SQL
>   Server 2005 for design-time
>   validation. To perform this operation,
>   you must open the Tools menu, click
>   Options and specify an instance of SQL
>   Server 2005 that is running and to
>   which you can connect in the Database
>   Tools, Design-time Validation Database
>   property page. When that is corrected,
>   you must then refresh or reload the
>   database project.

Any suggestions/update to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

- You don't mention if you have VS2008 SP1 installed, but this is a requirement for SQL Server 2008 support in Visual Studio ([KB956139](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/956139))
- Did you verify your instance name is correct? Tools > Options > Database Tools > Data Connections -> SQL server instance name: SQLEXPRESS (or the name you chose during install)
- Does your instance accept remote connections? (mine always does, not sure if this is required) ([Source](http://ankitjain.info/ankit/2008/05/05/visual-studio-database-project-not-loading/))

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but...

Were you able to get this combination working?  Visual Studio 2008 with SQL Server Express 2008?  I had the same issue that no matter what I entered into the instance fields in the Tools->Options->Database Tools boxes, it said I did not have them entered.

From what I could find on the interwebs, everything indicated that SQL Server Express 2008 should work with Visual Studio 2008 as long as you have the SP1 installed.  I tried reinstalling SP1, but received the same error - "no instance specified".

So I downloaded and installed SQL Express 2005 x64 and specified a new instance name, SQLEXPRESS2005.  Then I plugged that into Visual Studio 2008's settings and it worked right away.